# Hive how to convert date string which only last two digits of the year to a date format?

Tags: sql, hive

Is there a elegant way to convert a "date of birth" column with format like "28-Mar-99" to "1999-03-28" in hive?

I used the below query to handel these, it works well for the date after 2000, but for the date before 2000, it gives NULL or 20XX.

```
select a.d_cancel,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.d_cancel ,'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as new_date
from test_table a;

    d_cancel    new_date
0   12-Apr-07   2007-04-12
1   31-Dec-99   NULL
2   20-Sep-98   2098-09-20
```

Comment: How can you tell if 28-Mar-99 is before or after year 2000?

Comment: Why I want to ask these question is that there are many dates are like these in one dataset I need to process. From my understanding to the dataset, the 28-Mar-99 means 28-Mar-1999. If I want to get 28-Mar-2099, the query above should be able to get it correctly.

Comment: How do you know that the 28-Mar-99 means 28-Mar-1999? Probably you have some rules for recognizing year? Just implement them. Like this: ` case when cast(substr(your_date,8,2) as int)>$this_year then 19 else 20 end as sentury`. Note: Only you know your rules. If your dates can be in future as well as in the past then the information is already lost and cannot be recovered

Comment: Actually this field is a date of birth, so I know it can't be date after 2017. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
-- D/M/Y format (everywhere else)
  SELECT CAST(DAY(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
   + CAST(MONTH(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
   + CAST(YEAR(@date) AS varchar(4))
```

Comment: -- D/M/Y format (everywhere else)
SELECT CAST(DAY(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '-'
       + CAST(MONTH(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '/'
       + CAST(YEAR(@date) AS varchar(4))

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(10)='28-Mar-99'
SELECT CONVERT (DATE,@Day,126) AS ConvertedDate

DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(10)='28-Mar-99'
SELECT CAST (@Day AS DATE) AS ConvertedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solve it with this:

```
select
    if( to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( old_date_of_birth, "ddMMMyy"))) < from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),
            to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( old_date_of_birth, "ddMMMyy"))),
            concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( old_date_of_birth, "ddMMMyy"))))-100, SUBSTRING(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( old_date_of_birth, "ddMMMyy"))),5,10)) 
        ) as new_date_of_birth
from users
```

In my case the dates were in the format ddMMMyy (24MAR93) and I didnt have the problem of the null you mention. But I did have the issue with the future dates of birth.

Since it is a late answer I assume you solved already the issue, but it may help other users.